# Cual es la diferencia entre un modificador de acceso privado y el encapsulamiento es java?

Tags: java, poo

estoy estudiando Java y se me hace muy dificil entender todos los conceptos. Un modificador de acceso privado se pone frente a un atributo en una clase, de tal manera que otras clases no puedan acceder a esta. pero ahora llego a la encapsulacion donde dicen que es para ocultar datos y que estos no sehan utilizados por todas las clases....no son lo mismo ??????

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Un modificador de acceso es generalmente una palabra reservada del lenguaje.  Encapsulacion es un concepto.

Comment: Todo depende de donde se declare una variable. Si una variable se declara en la clase con el atributo privado, puede ser utilizado dentro de la clase por todos los metodos. Si declaras la variable dentro de un método, esta solo sera accesible dentro del método.  El primer caso es un modificador, el segundo es una encapsulacion

Answer (score 1):

## Encapsulamiento

El **[encapsulamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica))** es un concepto, que es parte del paradigma de la [programación orientada a objetos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_orientada_a_objetos).

Citando a la wikipedia (énfasis mío):

> Cada objeto está aislado del exterior, es un módulo natural, y la aplicación entera se reduce a un agregado o rompecabezas de objetos. El aislamiento **protege a los datos asociados de un objeto contra su modificación por quien no tenga derecho a acceder a ellos**, eliminando efectos secundarios e interacciones.
>
> De esta forma el usuario de la clase puede obviar la implementación de los métodos y propiedades para concentrarse solo en cómo usarlos. Por otro lado **se evita que el usuario pueda cambiar su estado de maneras imprevistas e incontroladas**.

Básicamente, por encapsulamiento, podemos entender que se trata de que cada *clase* de objeto es responsable, de manera aislada, de su función. Si otros objetos quieren interactuar con la clase, deberán hacerlo *solicitando* las acciones que esta debe realizar, pero no tendrán acceso a modificar directamente su estado y, muchas veces, tampoco tendrán acceso a *ver* cómo una clase particular implementa su funcionalidad.

## Modificadores de acceso en java

**`private`**, por otro lado, es un modificador de acceso y una palabra reservada del lenguaje `java`. Es decir, es parte de una *implementación* de un *lenguaje orientado a objetos*. A través de los modificadores de acceso `private`,  `protected` y `public` podemos definir la visibilidad de las distintas partes de nuestras clases de objetos. A través de esta visibilidad es que *implementamos* el encapsulamiento, pues definimos qué es lo que será visible por otros objetos y cómo estos otros objetos interactuarán con las instancias de una clase particular.

## Analogía

A modo de chiste y tratando de hacer una analogía, es como hablar de nutrición (el concepto de cómo te alimentas) y *tacos*, que es la manera particular en que los Mexicanos *implementan* el concepto de nutrición.

Answer (score 0):

El modificador de acceso `private` es una palabra reservada que sirve para que dicha propiedad de la clase no pueda ser utilizada por alguien diferente a la clase.

Dicho modificador se utiliza cuando se quiere hacer uso de la encapsulación, mediante los getters y los setters.

Por ejemplo:

```
// para un nombre
private nombre;
...
public getNombre() {
   return this.nombre;
}

public setNombre(nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En Java, el modificador de acceso privado y el encapsulamiento son conceptos relacionados pero distintos.

El modificador de acceso privado, representado por la palabra clave "private", se utiliza para restringir el acceso a miembros de una clase. Cuando se declara un miembro (variable o método) como privado, solo puede ser accedido directamente por otros miembros de la misma clase. Los miembros privados no son visibles ni accesibles desde fuera de la clase en la que se declaran. Esto ayuda a ocultar la implementación interna de una clase y proteger los datos de modificaciones no autorizadas.

El encapsulamiento, por otro lado, es un principio de programación orientada a objetos que combina datos y métodos relacionados en una sola entidad llamada clase. La idea principal del encapsulamiento es ocultar los detalles internos de implementación y proporcionar una interfaz pública para interactuar con el objeto. Esto significa que los datos y métodos internos de una clase se definen como privados y se acceden a través de métodos públicos, también conocidos como métodos de acceso (getters) y métodos de modificación (setters). El encapsulamiento permite controlar cómo se accede y modifica los datos internos de una clase, asegurando que se realicen las validaciones y operaciones necesarias antes de cambiar o acceder a los datos.